# How to make a button click in ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Please help me to solve this error. If click Save button display the following error. I am using ASP.NET Core 3.1 with Entity Framework Core.

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
> InvalidOperationException: The view 'Save' was not found. The following locations were searched:
>
> /Views/Home/Save.cshtml
> /Views/Shared/Save.cshtml
>
> InvalidOperationException: The view 'Save' was not found. The following locations were searched: /Views/Home/Save.cshtml /Views/Shared/Save.cshtml

Controller: HomeController

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
      CascadingModel model = new CascadingModel();
      model.Countries = (from customer in this.Context.Countries
                         select new SelectListItem
                         {
                             Value = customer.CountryId.ToString(),
                             Text = customer.CountryName
                         }).ToList();
      return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(int countryId, int stateId, int cityId)
{
      CascadingModel model = new CascadingModel();
      model.Countries = (from customer in this.Context.Countries
                         select new SelectListItem
                         {
                             Value = customer.CountryId.ToString(),
                             Text = customer.CountryName
                         }).ToList();

      model.States = (from customer in this.Context.States
                      where customer.CountryId == countryId
                      select new SelectListItem
                      {
                          Value = customer.StateId.ToString(),
                          Text = customer.StateName
                      }).ToList();

      model.Cities = (from customer in this.Context.Cities
                      where customer.StateId == stateId
                      select new SelectListItem
                      {
                          Value = customer.CityId.ToString(),
                          Text = customer.CityName
                      }).ToList();

      return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
[ActionName("Save")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult Save(CascadingModel model)
{
      if (ModelState.IsValid)
      {
          var newstaffrecords = new StaffDetailVM()
          {
              StaffId = model.StaffId,
              StaffName = model.StaffName,
              CountryName = model.CountryName,
              StateName = model.StateName,
              CityName = model.CityName,

          };
          this.Context.Stafftbl.Add(newstaffrecords);
          this.Context.SaveChanges();
      }

      return View(model);
}
```

View: Index.cshtml

```
<form asp-controller="Home" method="post">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="StaffId" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="StaffId" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="StaffId" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="StaffName" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="StaffName" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="StaffName" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="CountryId" class="control-label"></label>
            <select id="ddlCountries" name="CountryName" asp-for="CountryId" asp-items="Model.Countries" class="form-control">
               <option value="">--Please select--</option>
            </select>
            <span asp-validation-for="CountryId" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
         <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="StateId" class="control-label"></label>
            <select id="ddlStates" name="StateName" asp-for="StateId" asp-items="Model.States" class="form-control">
               <option value="">--Please select--</option>
             </select>
            <span asp-validation-for="StateId" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="CityId" class="control-label"></label>
             <select id="ddlCities" name="CityName" asp-for="CityId" asp-items="Model.Cities" class="form-control">
                  <option value="">--Please select--</option>
              </select>
            <span asp-validation-for="CityId" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" asp-action="Save" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You have `return View(model)` in your `HomeController` `Save` action method. Because the view name is not given in your return, the default will be your action method name i.e. `Save.cshtml`. This `Save.cshtml` must be present inside the Views --> Home folder or in any of the other folders that are mentioned in the error message.

Comment: My view is Index.cshtml in Home folder

Comment: Hello, did you able to resolve the issue? Do you still need any assistance on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't follow the ASP.Net MVC patterns (calling the view just like the action that returns it. In your case your View should be called Save.cshtml), you need to specify the name of the View you want to return.

### Solution:

It's pretty easy to solve, just add the "Index" as a parameter for the "return View(...) line.

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("Save")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult Save(CascadingModel model)
{
      if (ModelState.IsValid)
      {
          var newstaffrecords = new StaffDetailVM()
          {
              StaffId = model.StaffId,
              StaffName = model.StaffName,
              CountryName = model.CountryName,
              StateName = model.StateName,
              CityName = model.CityName,

          };
          this.Context.Stafftbl.Add(newstaffrecords);
          this.Context.SaveChanges();
      }

      return View("Index", model);
}
```

Here's a link to read some documentation about how to Name things to make it happen automatically, and how to use that "return View(...)" method to return any views you need: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/overview?view=aspnetcore-3.1#view-discovery

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you all for your effort to assist me. Using return **View("Index", model**
No error was displayed the page remained as Index view. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> If click Save button display the following error. I am using ASP.NET Core 3.1 with Entity Framework Core.

Well, the error you are getting possibly two main reasons as I have successfully reproduced your scenario.

[image]

**Reason 1:**

If you encounter the error before your `controller public IActionResult Save(CascadingModel model)` get call. In  that case you might need to set your `form  atrribute` like this `instead of``Its because you are using`explicite routing attribute`as`[ActionName("Save")]`

**Reason 2:**

However, if you are getting the error in this like `return View(model)` then the cause is different.

In this case, you may have two scenarios. After you saving the information either you want to go to `IActionResult Save(CascadingModel model)` view in that case you have to redirect to that view as per its `methods signature` for instance, your `save view` may need this model to pass `CascadingModel model = new CascadingModel()` in that case you have to redirect as below:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", model); //Or

return View("Index", model);
```

**Note:** Keep in mind, this model `View("Index", model)` should same type as of your `Index` `CascadingModel model = new CascadingModel()`.

**Output:**

[image]

**Reason 3:**

In this case, after adding new `stuff` you may want to display all the list of staff in a `List View Page` In that case you may redirect to that `List Page` therefore, you can do as following: Just redirect to that List pagge `return RedirectToAction("StaffList")`.

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ActionName("Save")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult Save(CascadingModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var newstaffrecords = new StaffDetailVM()
                {
                    StaffId = model.StaffId,
                    StaffName = model.StaffName,
                    CountryName = model.CountryName,
                    StateName = model.StateName,
                    CityName = model.CityName,

                };
                //  this.Context.Stafftbl.Add(newstaffrecords);
               // this.Context.SaveChanges();
            }

            return RedirectToAction("StaffList");
        }
```

**Sample List Page Action:**

```
public IActionResult StaffList()
        {
            var staffList = new List<StaffDetailVM>()
            {
                new StaffDetailVM() { StaffId=101,StaffName="Douda", CountryName = "USA",StateName ="New Jersy", CityName ="City In NJ" },
                new StaffDetailVM() { StaffId=102,StaffName="Kiron", CountryName = "UK",StateName ="London", CityName ="Hampe Shire" },
                new StaffDetailVM() { StaffId=103,StaffName="Farid", CountryName = "Canada",StateName ="Alberta", CityName ="Edmonton" },
                new StaffDetailVM() { StaffId=101,StaffName="Jhon", CountryName = "Australia",StateName ="Adelate", CityName ="West Adelate" },
               


            };
            return View(staffList);
        }
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your view is in `Index.cshtml` on your `Home` folder as you mention it on your comment, you should return it like that:

```
return View("~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml", model);
```